# Import "tensorflow.keras.optimizers" could not be resolved(reportMissingImports)

Tags: tensorflow

[image]

Can you help me to resolve my problem?

Comment: Please include your code and traceback error as text and not as an image.

Comment: Your screenshot does not match the error in your title

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is just a bug in Google Colab. If you try the import below it says the same:

```
import tensorflow.keras
```

However if you try using the import everything works. For example:

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
test=ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
```

Even code completion works as it should